# Reversing a linked-list

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, reverse

I am writing a simple recursive code to reverse a linked-list in Java. Strangely it returns the same node.

```
Node reverse(Node ptr) {
    if (ptr.link == null)
        return ptr;

    Node second = ptr.link;
    ptr.link = null;

    Node rest = reverse(second);
    rest.link = ptr;

    return rest;
}
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current approach won't work, the `rest` value that's being returned from the recursive call doesn't point to the *last* element in the list (which should be the insertion point for the nodes), instead it's pointing to the *first* element of the result. In other words, this line isn't correctly building the output:

```
rest.link = ptr;
```

For successfully reversing a list, one strategy is to use an accumulator parameter, so we can insert at the head of the list as the recursion unwinds - bear in mind that the recursion starts to "go back" in reverse order with respect to the elements in the list. Try this, it's a [tail-recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) solution:

```
Node reverse(Node ptr, Node acc) {
    if (ptr == null)
        return acc;
    Node second = ptr.link;
    ptr.link = acc;
    return reverse(second, ptr);
}
```

Call the above method like this:

```
Node reversedList = reverse(list, null);
```

Be aware that the input `list` *will* be modified in-place and won't be the same after the method returns, any variable that holds a reference to `list` will be affected. If that's a problem, you should create a copy of `list` before passing it to `reverse()`.

Comment: I have `Node ob` in which I'm doing all calculations. I'm calling it as `Node ob1 = reverse(ob,list); ob1.display();` where `display`simply prints the list. But it is printing the same list. Is my way of calling the function wrong?

Comment: @Faustus the reverse algorithm you posted is wrong, and it's not clear how you're printing it according to the comment. Start from scratch, use my answer as a starting point, it' working code. Also it's possible that the display code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Oscar is correct that the return value from recursive call does not point to the last element.

There is another algorithm that does not use accumulator parameter:

```
function reverse(node) {
  if (node.next == null)
    return node;
  var tail = reverse(node.next);
  node.next.next = node;
  node.next = null;
  return tail;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Node reverseNode(Node node){
Node head = null;
While(node.next != null){
    Node n = new Node(node.data);
    n.next = head;
    head = n;
    node = node.next;
}
return head;}
```

You know you don't have to write a recursive function